# Supporting various languages (Hindi, Arabic, Tamil) in Android

Tags: android, arabic, hindi, tamil

I have been building an app whose base function is to translate things into various languages.

However, I can't find a way to let the TextView support languages like Arabic, Hindi, Tamil, Telugu and so on.

So far, I have seen that device manufacturers are controlling which language their device supports. Like, Samsung supports Hindi in India but no one else does.

I am also providing my custom fonts for Arabic, Hindi, Tamil and other languages in assets, still nothing works.

Any workaround?

Comment: I am going to try WebViews for this and see if they support.

Comment: Nope, no way to do that by yourself without a lot of effort, but Samsung supports most of these languages, because sometimes they are awesome lol. The thing is that usually, in most countries, its the carrier that decides this, and not the OEM.

Comment: This is the most shit thing I have come across in Android. Not everyone uses Samsung. I praise Samsung for providing Hindi Support in India though, but I am planning a translation app for international use.

Comment: Did you get any breakout in the recent part? Is there a solution possible now?

Comment: Not yet. Recent Android versions do support Indic languages but this is something that I think we'll have to wait on Google for