# Android : How to display Non-English text in eclipse's "Graphical Layout"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, adt, textview

I am designing UI using eclipse's graphical layout. When I place a text view content in English language it shows content correctly. But when I set content of text in XML file to Non-English language such as Arabian, Chinese, Hindi or Thai,etc, The content is shown as blank. When I run the project which have content of text in foreign language on hardware android smart phone, it show content correctly in correct language there. I'm wondering how can I get eclipse graphical layout display other language?

[image: Display english text correctly]

[image: Failed to display Thai Text. But when run on hardware, it shows correctly]

Before asking this question, I have look into following similar questions.

[Hindi language support for Android - text shows up as boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759242/hindi-language-support-for-android-text-shows-up-as-boxes)

[Non-English words in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918432/non-english-words-in-android-application?lq=1)

[Supporting various languages (Hindi, Arabic, Tamil) in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813466/supporting-various-languages-hindi-arabic-tamil-in-android?rq=1)

But I don't find their answer fix my problem as most of the answers is about "How to get text display correctly on device and emulator" but not on "How to get foreign text display correctly on eclipse's graphical layout"

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: do you put the text in your strings.xml file or inside the layouts?

Comment: I tried both. but none of them work.

Comment: In image above, I put text in string.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found solution to the problem. All we need to do is select android API version below 19 to have foreign text display correctly.

[image]